# XML DOM createchild takes Node instread of Element

Tags: java, xml

I am creating a XML using DOM as below using online examples,

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docfac= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docb= docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = docb.newDocument();

    // root
    Element rootElement = (Element)doc.createElement("TEST");

    doc.appendChild(rootElement); //Compiler error
...
```

appenchild takes Node object, not Element object.  I was trying to use Node but, it seems like there is no methods exposed to set attribute, therefore, I can't really use node.

Any help would be really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please verify the packages you've imported : `import org.w3c.dom.Document` and `import org.w3c.dom.Element;` and change `docfac.newDocumentBuilder()`;

No need to type cast the `org.w3c.dom.Element` because `doc.createElement("TEST")` returns an object of `org.w3c.dom.Element` which is a sub-interface of `org.w3c.dom.Node`.

```
org.w3c.dom.Element rootElement = doc.createElement("TEST");
doc.appendChild(rootElement)
```